# USB drives not recognized all of a sudden (module usb_storage not loading)

Tags: udev, usb-drive, lsusb

**I am very close to the solution, just need to know how to get usb-storage to load.**

I have tried most of the advice on askubuntu and other sites, `usb_storage` enable to `fdisk -l`.  But I am unable to find steps to get it working again.

**`sudo lsusb`**:

```
Bus.... skipped 4 lines
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 413c:3012 Dell Computer Corp. Optical Wheel Mouse 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 413c:2105 Dell Computer Corp. Model L100 Keyboard 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8564:1000
```

**`sudo dmseg | tail`**:

```
[   69.567948] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   74.084041] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[   74.240484] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[   74.256033] scsi5 : usb-storage 1-6:1.0
[   74.256145] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   74.256147] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[   74.257290] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usb-storage
```

**`fdisk -l`**:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   972656639   486327296   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       972658686   976771071     2056193    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       972658688   976771071     2056192   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I think I need steps to install and get usb_storage module working.

**`sudo modprobe -v usb-storage`**:

```
insmod /lib/modules/3.2.0-48-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko
```

**`sudo udevadm monitor --udev`**:

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing

UDEV  [4757.144372] add      /module/usb_storage (module)
UDEV  [4757.146558] remove   /module/usb_storage (module)
UDEV  [4757.148707] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-6 (usb)
UDEV  [4757.149699] add      /bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage (drivers)
UDEV  [4757.151214] remove   /bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage (drivers)
UDEV  [4757.156873] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [4757.160903] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/host9 (scsi)
UDEV  [4757.164672] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/host9/scsi_host/host9 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [4757.165163] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/host9/scsi_host/host9 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [4757.165440] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/host9 (scsi)
```

**Narrowing down more: Seems like I need usb_storage to load as a module**

**`lsmod | grep usb`**:

```
usbserial              37201  0 
usbhid                 41937  0 
hid                    77428  1 usbhid
```

Still no usb driver mounted. Nor does a device show up in /dev. Any step by step process to debug and fix this will be really helpful.

Comment: New sysemd way of `dmesg` to look for errors: `journalctl -xe -k -p warning`, `systemctl --failed`...